# VS Code: search in both file names _and_ file contents

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to search in the currently opened folder for a certain string not only in file names but also within the files themselves?

I know I can use Ctrl+P to search in file names, or Ctrl+Shift+F (the magnifying glass icon in the sidebar) to search within the files, but those are two distinct steps. It would be great if this could be done in one fell swoop.

Thanks.

nvx

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps... I've been trying to find extensions to do the very same thing for awhile now.

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

[image]

Enter your query and filter the filetypes

[image: Enter your query and filter the filetypes]

Comment: Thank you for the comment; however, I am afraid that this does not answer my question. Your response is the equivalent of Ctrl+Shift+F (the magnifying glass icon in the sidebar) which **only searches in file contents.** It **does not search in file names,** as specified in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way that might work for you; search within a certain folder. I wanted to search all my controller classes so I right clicked on the folder that contains them all and selected Search in folder. That opens the search to your selected folder and you can then search for the text that you want.

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Still, I am afraid that the referenced menu item is only available for the _subfolders_ of the currently opened folder, not the "root" folder itself.

Comment: @nvx, did you try it? For me it searched all files in the selected folder.

Comment: Ah, I see – I could manually change the _files to include_ field to `./` to search in the entire "root" folder. However, the issue remains: **this is file contents search.** Any file name match will be completely ignored (see my comment to the previous reply that references the very same search dialog).

Comment: Right, it seems there is on such feature in vs code right now. We need it though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.82.1 on MacOS and the `shift` + `cmd` + `F` seems can search both **file name** and **file content** at the same time after **toggle search details**.
(I think `shift` + `ctrl` + `F` could do the same thing with same version of VSCode)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just tested it in the latest VS Code on Windows, and I am afraid that you are not correct (as far as I know, VS Code behaves identically in this regard irrespective of OS). _What I asked for was a "one stop solution" not requiring me to specify the same search string twice._ You can easily confirm this in the respective search dialog by searching for a string present in some file name but not in any file itself.